# NullReferenceException: Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object (How is that so and I should I solve it?)

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

I am stuck several days because of this problem, which I am almost on the verge of giving up. (Using Unity Engine 2019.3a by the way). The TextButtonName.text can't read what TextButton is throwing to it. Meanwhile, when I did a Debug.Log test, the console shows what is the text in the TextButton. What the console showed about Debug.Log() thing should be the value of a variable assigned (hence, the

Is there any way that whatever is the text at the button, will be the value that can be used for Switch Statements? If there is a way (I am sure there is), how? Thanks.

```
//When pressed, ButtonPress() will be triggered and will go to Experiment Information Scene
public void ButtonPressTutorial(){
    //TextButton = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    TextButton = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
    TextButtonName.text = TextButton;
    /* TextButton, although has value shown in Debug.Log, the problem is that
    it throws a NULL value when being thrown to TextButtonName.text Why is that? Is there that I need to do?*/
    Debug.Log(TextButton);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(5);}
```

Switch statements:

```
        switch (TextButtonName.text) { 
        case "  Tutorial":
            ExpNum.text = "Tutorial";
            ExpTitle.text = "Coke With Mentos Experiment";
            ExpDetails.text = "//Details will be shown here";
            break;
        case "Experiment 1 Button":
            ExpNum.text = "Experiment 1";
            ExpTitle.text = "Lemon Volcano Experiment";
            ExpDetails.text = "//Details will be shown here";
            break;
        default:
            ExpNum.text = "No Experiments";
            break; }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Looks like `TextButtonName` is null. Be sure you've assigned that reference somewhere in your script. I also recommend updating your variable names. Having a variable called "name" that actually points to a text field, not a name, and having a variable called "button" that points to a string, not a button, is a recipe for programmer confusion and bugs.

Comment: If this exception behaviour is consistent, you may want to place a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and check every variable to spot which one is null.